# How to simplify this sum of the derivative of 2 integrals?

Tags: integration

[image]

Specifically in part a), I cannot actually express f'(x) and g'(x) without the use integrals, and also when I try to combine them nothing seems to cancels out. So in the end, I expressed f'(x)+g'(x) as something like $2e^{-x^2} \cdot (\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2}dt- x\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x^2t^2}dt )$

(I computed f'(x) by fundamental theorem of calculus, and g'(x) by differentiation under integral sign)

Comment: PLEASE rewrite your title to be *informative*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ f'(x)=2e^{-x^2}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt $$
and $$ g'(x)=-2x\int_0^1 e^{-x^2(1+t^2)}dt=-2xe^{-x^2}\int_0^1 e^{-x^2t^2}dt=-2e^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{-u^2}du $$
wih $u=xt$. It follows directly that $f'+g'=0$.

Comment: How did you think of the substitution?

Comment: To get the same bounds of the first integral.